# Managing file open and close responsibilities with different objects

Tags: python, file, contextmanager

In a main method, `my_object` needs access to several members of `passed_object`, including a file that is opened (`passed_file = passed_object.create_file()`.  An example of this:

```
import os

def main():

    print('Start of program...')
    passed_object = PassedObject()
    my_object = MyObject(passed_object)

    my_object.use_passed_object()
    print('End of program.')

class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, passed_object):
        self.passed_object = passed_object

    def use_passed_object(self):
        f = self.passed_object.create_file()
        print('attribute:')
        print(self.passed_object.attr1)
        print('contents of first file:')
        print(list(f))

class PassedObject(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.attr1 = 'some attribute string'

    def create_file(self):

        path = '/tmp'
        files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) 
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))]

        f = open(files[0], 'r')
        return f

main()
```

The problem: `passed_object` creates a file object(s) that is needed by `my_object`, and by others not shown in this simple example.  How can I close these file objects when `my_object` is done with it without breaking encapsulation?

Potential solutions I see:

- don't pass `passed_object`: pass `passed_object.create_file()` and `passed_object.attr1`, then use a context manager in main `with open...`.  However, I now have to pass in each attribute/created object to `my_class`.
- write method `my_object.close_file()`, and call it from main.  This seems to break encapsulation also, as main shouldn't need to know about this.
- write a `my_object.__del__()` method that closes the file.
- don't worry about closing it; your program terminates in a few lines.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't mix responsibilities. There is no way you can refactor your solution to not mix responsibilities?

Comment: What does `PassedObject.create_file` actually do? Does it return a file object? What issues arise when you close that file object early? Without more information it's difficult to tell exactly what your issue is given these stripped-down classes.

Comment: Your example really mixes layers of abstraction/responsibilities. Why PassedObject a class to start with, it has just one method?  how would you ever get `f` fromit once it is never returned? I think the proper answer is that there is no 'proper pythonic way' to close a file, becuase the orginal setting (opening it elsewhere to handle afterwards) seems unpythonic and intent for doing it is rather unclear.

Comment: @Rafael can you be more specific?  The passed class is a part of an external library, I have no control over its implementation.

Comment: @Blender PassedObject.create_file actually creates/opens several files, which are accessed/modified by other PassedObject.methods() (not shown here for simplicity).  Take it as an assumption that it should remain open until `my_object` is done with it.

Comment: Does `create_file` just create a file object and return it, or does `PassedObject` keep a reference to it? If `PassedObject` holds the file object, it should have a `close_file` method or something similar which cleans it up. Otherwise, `MyObject` can close the file when it is done with it.

Comment: `create_file` just returns an object; there is no `PassedObject.close_file()` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I wrote an answer, read the solution there. Just one more remark: do not ever use `my_object.__del__()` for something like this. Python is not C++ and `__del__` is nothing like a C++ destructor. This would not help, and it could hurt.

Comment: @zvone Can you modify your solution to close `f` at the end of `my_object`s life, instead of the method call?  In the actual problem, `f` may be called by several different methods, that depend on user input, before closing.

Comment: @zvone is there a destructor-like equivalent in python?

Comment: There, I added it to my answer. Context managers are commonly used for these situations, where destructors would be used in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the simplest situation (because details are missing):

- `PassedObject.create_file` just opens a file, returns it and does not keep a reference to it
- Usage of the file is limited to the scope of `MyObject.use_passed_object`

The solution is simple: close the file when `use_passed_object` finishes:

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, passed_object):
        self.passed_object = passed_object

    def use_passed_object(self):
        f = self.passed_object.create_file()
        try:
            print('attribute:')
            print(self.passed_object.attr1)
            print('contents of first file:')
            print(list(f))
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Alternatively, since `passed_object.create_file()` is just returning a `file` object, which supports context manager interface, you can also do this:

```
    def use_passed_object(self):
        with self.passed_object.create_file() as f:
            print('attribute:')
            print(self.passed_object.attr1)
            print('contents of first file:')
            print(list(f))
```

In a more complex scenario (e.g. something other than builtin `file` is returned), you could create you own contextmanager which encapsulates access to `passed_object.create_file()`...

---

On the other hand, if the file is used by multiple methods of `MyObject` during its lifetime, you need a contextmanager around the usage of a `MyObject` instance.

To do that, you'll have to:

- remember in `MyObject` which file(s) it opened (you'll have to do that anyway to use it in multiple methods)
- implement `MyObject.close` which closes all of those files

```py
class MyObject(object):

    def close(self):
        for file_object in self.opened_files:
            file_object.close()
```

Then implement a context manager and use it for this.

**Option 1**: use `contextlib.closing`

```
import contextlib

def main():

    print('Start of program...')
    passed_object = PassedObject()

    with contextlib.closing(MyObject(passed_object)) as my_object:
        my_object.use_passed_object()

    print('End of program.')
```

**Option 2**: implement context manager interface on `MyObject` itself

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()


def main():

    print('Start of program...')
    passed_object = PassedObject()

    with MyObject(passed_object) as my_object:
        my_object.use_passed_object()

    print('End of program.')
```